# I want show My timer on my front page product

Tags: magento2

I am trying to show my timer on home page product .currently this product is showing on product view.Below is the code  , what I am trying to this i want to change this code for my widgets.phtm page. mean i am getting all product from product widget on home page . let me know how can i asign these code for my frontpage product

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magebuzz\Timecountdown\Block\Timecountdown" name="timecountdown.product.view"
                       template="timer.phtml" after="-" ifconfig="timecountdown/general/show_in_product_page" cacheable="false"/>
            </referenceContainer>
```